# iOS: Back toolbar bar button item

Tags: ios

I need the back arrow toolbar bar button item.

In identifier of bar button item, there is play, refresh, reload, and stop.

I need the image of play, but flipped 180 degrees.

Is there a way to flip the image with code? If not, where can I find this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Google search for play button vector graphic. Make the one you want the image of the button. Should still be able to tell the button to maintain it's bar button style.

Comment: Might want to specify that the background is transparent.

Comment: Could also use/customize parts of the PSD found here: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2010/06/14/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Comment: It can be a pain to try an extract a specific graphic from an SDK object. If you just need it for a UIBarButtonItem, I would seriously consider finding the same graphic as a PNG or having it made for you. There are plenty of mobile artifact images floating around on the Web.

Comment: Another thing you can do is right-click on an enum type right in Xcode. Click "jump to definition." Browse the implementation class to see if a type even exists for the graphic you want.

Comment: The downside is the (real) back button is part of the OS and in case things change in future versions, your back button will still look like the old version → Not future friendly. Might not be a big issue in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

here's a simple work around:
declare your button with "initWithTitle" and set the title to @"◀" (it's just a unicode symbol).
Use @"▶" for the forward button to make it consistent.
I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: But a blue rectangle will also appear around the play button

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward option is to draw a white triangle of the appropriate size and orientation in an image editor, stick it in an image view, and then use that image view for a bar button item's custom view.

I wouldn't try to use the UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay image. I don't know if manipulating system images is expressly proscribed, but Apple generally doesn't smile on misuse of system items. When you get right down to it, it's just a white triangle, so it'd be hard to tell the difference between drawing your own or reversing theirs. That just seems like all the more reason to draw your own.